# Change from a fragment inside a view to another view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

So i have a fragment(initial) inside my home, home has a bottom nav bar, and in that one i manage the fragments i have. In my initial fragment(initial) i want to have a buttom that when you click on it, it loads a new view, but i dont want to have the bottom nav bar there (home).

Here is my method for the buttom:

```
fun loadCreateView() {
        val intent = Intent(this, createLobby::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

I have a red line under Intent saying that:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
<init>(Context!, Class<*>!)defined in android.content.Intent
<init>(String!, Uri!)defined in android.content.Intent
```

`Context!, String!, Uri!` beeing underlined with red

if i change `this` for `getcontext()` I can compile but app crashes when i click on the botton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that i had to put the method in the view that contains the fragment, that solved it